# Boiling water efficiency

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, steam

What is the most efficient method to boil water without thermal energy. eg. burning gas. Reducing pressure reduces the energy required but is there something on a molecular level that is the most efficient?

Are microwaves the most efficient or does generating microwaves take more energy that boiling the water??

Comment: How do you feel about a solar water heater?

Comment: How do you feel about running up Everest? Gets the BP down to about 60 Deg C. Otherwise, excluding capital costs Solar will be good. Have not done a test of 1 litre of water between my microwave and my induction hob but would have to put some effort to compare relative power then figure out area / volume etc. But I will let you play.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what it is you want to ask. There is no way to boil anything without thermal energy since that's what it comes down to. Even lowering pressure requires thermal energy for it to boil. Microwaves end up as thermal energy in the water to boil it too. Maybe you are asking about boiling something through a method other than heat conduction?

Comment: Unless you just happen to get the microwaves as a freebie, it costs energy to generate them.  Consider trying to get the freebie of energy absorption from the surroundings...

Comment: To tie on the @DKNguyen's comment, you also need to be more precise in what you mean by "efficient."  Efficiency in engineering is about output over input.  Warming up sun tea in a jar in the sun may be effectively free, but it isn't necessarily efficient in how it uses the sun's heat.  Similarly, the energy to reduce pressure must be included in the "input" part of the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have realized, if you need to change the state of something, energy is required.  Efficiency requires a definition of what is "useful," in this case you could be aiming for the phase change or the increased temperature.

If you seek the increased temperature, look to put in a place where energy can enter easily but has difficulty exiting.  Think hot car in the sun: light enters, turns into infrared and heat and has difficulty exiting.

If you seek the phase change, you could be looking for the reduction of liquid or the increase of gas.  If you need the reduction of liquid, you just need to have some place for it to go - just exposing it to "dry" air is enough to promote evaporation.

If you need the gas, that is the most interesting case and what steam tables are good for.  You need to find the state that has the division of phases you seek (x% liquid, 100%-x% gas) and differs least from your initial state in energy.  Then you can strive to remove the gas, extract as much energy from the removed, pure gas as possible without putting it into a different phase.  Generally, this will involve reducing pressure and waiting for the fluid to absorb energy from the surroundings (increased volume should eventually result in lower temperature) until a desired liquid- gas division forms, then slowly sucking out just the gas (pushing it out will cause it to liquify from increased pressure!).

Depending on environmental conditions, you may find it difficult to create the pistons and seals necessary for this.  At room temp, should be as simple as filling a partially expanded piston with water and hanging a weight from it where the weight tries to expand the piston.  Hard part is the vaccum pump you need to pull the gas out (raising the weight).

Comment: Thank you Able for your answer. I wish to generate steam without burning biomass/ gas etc and it seems an immersion is the best way for that. Your answer has helped significantly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very well-posed question but I will try to take a swing at it.

What you want is a lossless method of delivering heat energy to a mass of water. This would be a simple electric immersion heater dipped into the water, where all the heat generated in the heater gets into the water without any leakage, at 100% efficiency. However, the electricity had to come from somewhere, and if we exclude burning fuel to generate the electricity then this method, while "lossless" in itself, doesn't count. Note also that in this case you are forced to include transmission losses for the electricity.

Microwaves are efficient too, as the efficiency of a magnetron tube can be as high as 70%, but similar comments apply here regarding where the electricity came from.

Using a heat pump to move thermal energy into a tank of water is far more efficient than an immersion heater because it's easier to move heat than it is to create it, and all the efficiency losses of the pump itself are given up to the water too, but here again it takes electricity to run a heat pump so we are once again stuck.

Focusing sunbeams onto a body of water in a container with black walls doesn't require a flame, but the sun itself consists of a scorchingly hot plasma so this technique, strictly speaking, is not "flameless" either.

At this juncture we can propose using a solar cell array to power the heat pump, but with the sun involved we still start out with hot flames!

Comment: Hi there, and thank you for answering my vague question. I am wandering in the dark with an idea of a map.  And half a brain..

Comment: You have put my mind to rest that I haven't overlooked anything and confirmed my project is dubious and uncertain.